# How to work with DrawingImage in separate XAML files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several XAML files representing DrawingImages (converted from SVG in Blend). I'm wondering, what's the best way of working with these?

Can I somehow place links to them in a resource dictionary?
What if I'd like to refer to them in code?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Drawing as the Source to an Image control...see the example here.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx

Also this long article that discusses graphics described in XAML and their usage.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22716/Graphic-in-XAML-and-WPF

As for managing your "drawings"....keep them in separate .XAML files.

You can then load a drawing on demand by using XamlReader.Load().

- http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/10/lazy-load-xaml-content-from-external.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115108/Lazy-Load-XAML-content-from-External-File-and-Vice

OR

You could merge all your drawings into your App.Xaml ResourceDictionary....(you'd need to put each drawing in it's own ResourceDictionary so it could be merged in with MergedDictionaries).

Note, you have to be careful with ResourceDictionaries, especially when using the "merging" facility...there are some performance/lookup gotchas.

Comment: I obviously did get this far. I can easily use multiple DrawingImage instances and store them within a ResourceDictionary.
My question is - what if I wanted to have each DrawingImage in its own file? Would I need to enclose each DrawingImage in a ResourceDictionary and then merge them? Or can I have resource dictionary and somehow have it reference XAML files with DrawingImage as top element?